# Pass multiple values from radio button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Currently I have a list of delivery points where you can choose a specific point using a radio button. When choosing a specific point, I need some linked information to this point to store in the database, for example the shipping provider. I will give an example :

> I have 2 delivery points, one with id 123 and other one with id 456, if I choose the 456 it is shipped with provider B and when I choose 123 it is shipped with provider A.

My first idea was to make a hidden field that we update with javascript when we select a point, but in this case I rely on javascript and because it is one step of passing an order we want to ensure you can also make an order when no javascript is enabled.

Another idea is to pass a json as value for the radio button, for example :

```
= f.radio_button :relais_number, {:relais_number => so_point.identifiant, :shipping_method => "so_colissimo"}.to_json, :id => "point_relais_#{index}", :"data-service-provider" => "so_colissimo"
```

What is the best? Drop the support of no use of javascript or passing it in JSON format? The advantage of passing it as a json is that I can easily pass more fields.

Comment: If what you're selecting is a point, can't you have the linked information in the database from the beginning, and find it through the point id?

Comment: @JoelLundberg No, because I get the id of the points from an api. I need the shipping provider from the form. If I have the shipping provider I can do an after update to get all the neccesary information. The ideal way is that I can pass all the values directly from the form so I don't have to use an after callback and 2 times the api call.

Comment: I see! I would definitely go with JSON in the values then.

Comment: Hi, couldn't you store the provider value along with the ID with an underscore for the radio button value ? Then when the radio button is selected, you could split them in the controller and save both in db. Ex, in the view , radio button one would have value as  123_shipperA and radio button two would have 456_ShipperB. I think that way you could pass both values when one radio is selected. Just a thought..

Comment: @Sonu Thanks, but is it not better to just use json then?

Comment: I am sorry - I havent used JSON much to comment on that...